# Samba on a Beowulf Cluster

Tags: samba, cluster

Is this possible? I have only been able to locate resources related to running scientific applications.

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you're trying to do? It's not clear to me why you'd want to run samba on a cluster. (And do you want samba servers, or clients?)

Comment: I currently have a Samba server. I would like to cluster it, purely for educational purposes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are several kinds of computer clusters, with different purposes.

A "beowulf cluster" is generally referring to a set of machines configured with services for parallel processing. The purpose is to spread computationally intensive tasks over several computing nodes (computers).

Other types of clusters are meant to ensure redundancy and reliability, spreading data and/or services over several computers so that a failure does not disrupt the service.

I don't think the samba project has a simple and mature set of services for this purpose but there is an entry in the wiki that seems to be a good starting point for what you are trying to do: [Clustered samba](http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Clustered_Samba)